# Aproximating difference equation by differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following difference equation

$$ C_{n+1} = C_n + \frac{1}{4C_n}$$

with $C_0 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ given and am interested in the speed at which $C_n$ diverges to $\infty$ as $n \to  \infty$.

Up until now, I failed to derive an explicit solution for $C_n$ and I am also not sure whether a nice formula exists (if so, I would of course be interested). However, solving the *corresponding* differential equation

$C' = \frac{1}{4C}$

yields the solution

$$ C(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2C_0^2 + t}{2}},$$

i.e., an expression of order $O(\sqrt{t})$. When plotting the first terms $C_n$ this pattern also appears.

I was wondering whether there is some general theory on how to approximate the asymptotics of the solution of a difference equation by the using the solution of the differential equation and how it can be used in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about a general theory, but you can easily check your conjecture: \begin{align*}
C_{n+1}^2&=\left(C_n{\left[1+\frac1{4C_n^2}\right]}\right)^2\\[.4em]
&=C_n^2\left[1+\frac1{2C_n^2}+o\left(\frac1{C_n^2}\right)\right],
\end{align*}
that is,
$$C_{n+1}^2-C_n^2\sim\frac12.$$
It follows that $C_n^2\sim\frac n2$, i.e., $C_n\sim\sqrt\frac n2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_n=c_n/(2i)$, yielding
\begin{align}
c_{n+1}=\frac{c_n^2-1}{c_n}.
\end{align}
Computing the first few  terms of $c_n$ we have that
\begin{align}
c_0=2C_0,\quad c_1=\frac{c_0^2-1}{c_0},\quad c_2=\frac{c_0^4-3c_0^2+1}{c_0(c_0^2-1)},\quad c_3=\frac{c_0^8-7c_0^6+13c_0^4-7c_0^2+1}{c_0(c_0^2-1)(c_0^4-3c_0^2+1)},\dots
\end{align}
Of note is that $c_n$ follows the pattern
\begin{align}
c_n=\frac{s_n}{c_0\Pi_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k},\quad s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}r_k c_0^{2k}
\end{align}
where the coefficients on $r_k$ follow [this series from the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A147990).
Let us introduce $t_n=s_n/c_n$, which gives the system of equations
\begin{align}
s_{n+1}=s_n^2-t_n^2,\quad t_{n+1}=s_nt_n,
\end{align}
which is covered directly in [Polynomials Associated with Reciprocation](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Kimberling/kimberling56.pdf).